# share image with caption to social media using intent android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am facing a small problem in sharing image using intent. This is my case, I want to share an image with caption (caption may be link or text), when i used the below code

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

            shareIntent.setType("image/*");

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.whatsapp_promotion);
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);

            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                    getContentResolver(), bitmap, null, null);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            shareIntent
                    .putExtra(
                            Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                            "**my message with URL **");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Via..."));
```

I can share with hangout, whatsapp, twitter etc., but am not able to share with facebook. So what i decided is one image with the caption that's it, that can be share in whatsapp, hangout, facebook etc.,

How to do this, please help me out

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share image and text to Facebook through Intent.For that,you have to use Facebook API.

Comment: yeah i read that point, but we can share the image with facebook know, can we add the caption for that image ??

Comment: What do you mean by caption for image?

Comment: please refer whatsapp.. when we share image with friends, we can add the title (caption) for that image know.. i need the same concept that's all

Comment: I don't think that it is possible.You better use Facebook API if you want to share image along with text or Intent if you want to share only text

Answer (score 0):

You need the Facebook sdk, and then you can do this:

```
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(
            getYourBitmapMethod()).build();

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo).setRef("This is a test").build();

    ShareDialog.show(YourActivity.this, content);
```

Comment: thanks to sharing the code.. but please refer the whatsapp.. when we are sharing the image with friends, there is one caption (heading or title) is available know.. so i want that kind of code to share the image with title

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation to share photos on facebook
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#photos

Here is the code snippet to build content for your image

```
Bitmap image = ...
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
        .setBitmap(image)
        .setCaption("Enter your caption")
        .build();
SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
        .addPhoto(photo)
        .build();
```

And then to share `ShareDialog.show(YourActivity.this, content);`

Complete documentation for sharing on facebook here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android